Laravel url() Sometimes Return https and http Randomly
I'm using Laravel 10.32.1 and the url() method behaves very strangely. My site uses https and I expect that url will follow it. APP_URL in .env also configured to https.
Here is my code:
<!--
{{ url('signin/oauth/google/a.png') }}
{{ url('signin/oauth/google') }}
{{ url('assets/img/logo.png') }}
{{ env('APP_URL') }}
-->
<img src="{{url('assets/img/logo.png')}}" class="d-none" />
<div id="g_id_onload"
data-client_id="<?=env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID')?>"
data-login_uri="<?= url('signin/oauth/google') . $intent->getParams() ?>"
data-auto_prompt="false">

Here is the resulting html:
<!--
http://auth.example.com/signin/oauth/google/a.png
http://auth.example.com/signin/oauth/google
http://auth.example.com/assets/img/logo.png
https://auth.example.com
-->
<img src="https://auth.example.com/assets/img/logo.png" class="d-none" />
<div id="g_id_onload"
data-client_id="MY_CLIENT_ID"
data-login_uri="http://auth.example.com/signin/oauth/google?"
data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

Somehow it will only return https in src and href attributes, otherwise it would just return http.

As per docs The generated URL will automatically use the scheme (HTTP or HTTPS) and host from the current request being handled by the application. Please clarify that do you want all the URL should be generated with https?

@Subha Indeed, I expect the generated URL will automatically use the scheme (HTTP or HTTPS) and host from the current request. Those urls are generated in the same request, but why it randomly switches between http and https?

You can use URL::forceScheme('https'); inside the boot() method of AppServiceProvider which will force the HTTPS across all URL generations.

@Subha Yes, I ended up using it. Just curious why did it behave like that.
